# java int size fixed or variable?

Tags: java

Is integer size in java of fixed length or variable size?

ex: 1 or 10000 does both the number takes same space during allocation?

Comment: BTW, if you need to know number of bits used for each primitive type,  it is available at runtime in the equivalent wrapper class, in the `SIZE` field, e.g. `Integer.SIZE` is 32. This number is fixed for all types, and is same of 32 and 64 bit versions of JVM.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Java integers are 32 bits (4 octets) as per the JLS.

> The *integral types* are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively.

Source: [JLS §4.2 Primitive Types and Values](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#85587)

Comment: The JLS defines the ranges, which imply that (at least) 32-bits of storage must be used (assuming a fixed size) - but it doesn't define what ints must look like in memory.  Some (obscure) platforms may choose to use 64-bits to represent them (say 64-bit platforms without fast access to high and low portions of a word) and say may even use variable sizes.  In in theory the answer to the question could be that 1 and 10000 take different amounts of space on the heap.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: did you miss this part? "The _integral types_ are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively"

Comment: That's to define their behavior in terms of wraparound (overflow), shifting, bit-wise negation and so on, but it doesn't constrain the implementation's internal representation.

Or are you suggesting that an implementation which doesn't have native two-s complement integers, or didn't have byte accessible memory, etc, couldn't implement a compliant JVM by applying the appropriate logic to make it appears as if these numbers were behaving as designed?

Comment: It's equivalent an implementation choosing to internally store some Strings as byte[] rather than char[], even though they must make it appear as the latter.

Comment: Note also that in places where the representation is constained (e.g. stack layout) byte, short and int, are actually the same size - see for example: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#28851.

Of course what you really care about is heap storage most of the type, and here a JVM is not constained, see: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#16066

Answer (score 7):

It's fixed in size. All ints in Java are 32 bits, both from the programmer's perspective and the machine's.

The [Java VM specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#22239), which describes the JVM bytecode format, mentions that each `int` is 32 bits. (Aside: `boolean` values can take up any number of bits, as can objects.)

Comment: Sure, but the bytecode format doesn't dictate the heap layout, which is completely up to the JVM.  I read the question regarding allocation as talking about the space on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

An `int` or an `Integer` has fixed size. A `BigInteger` has variable size.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [datasizes for the Java primitive types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Interesting to note here is that the size of `boolean` is not clearly defined, but it's usually 8 bits.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the JVM implementation.

In *typical* implementations, boolean, byte, char, short and int will be 32-bits always on the stack while long will be 64-bits on the stack.  In *typical* implementations bytes, chars, shorts, ints and longs will be their "native" size in arrays (that is, 8, 16, 16, 32 and 64-bit respectively).

In *typical* implementations the size of integers within structures will be their native size if alignment allows it.

It's certainly possible that some very unusual implementations could use variable length integers for structures, or even on the stack or in arrays (but that's even harder to imagine and more obscure) - but I certainly haven't seen any that do.