# What is the storage requirement for a primitive int in a 64-bit JVM?

Tags: memory, jvm

I know that there is 4 byte storage required for an int and some header info but don't get it enough to understand it thoroughly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java int size fixed or variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048535/java-int-size-fixed-or-variable)

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/

Answer (score 0):

JVM does not store separate `int` values in heap, it stores objects. If an object contains the `int` field, it will take at least 4 bytes. However it may take more if it's necessary for alignment of other fields or the object itself. Also adding a new `int` field to an existing object may not increase its size at all if the object had the alignment gap big enough to fit the new `int` field. This is totally up to the implementation and may vary depending on the JVM vendor/version used and even its options.